# python - play audio samples simultaneously and at different volumes

Tags: python, audio, pygame, volume, simultaneous

I'm trying to play audio samples simultaneously and at different volumes on a Raspberry Pi using python:

```
from time import sleep
import threading
import pygame

def play(sample,volume):
    sample.set_volume(volume)
    sample.play()

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/Desktop/sample.wav')
thr=threading.Thread(target=play,args=([sound,1]),kwargs={})
thr.start()
sleep(1)
thr=threading.Thread(target=play,args=([sound,0.5]),kwargs={})
thr.start()
sleep(1)
thr=threading.Thread(target=play,args=([sound,0.25]),kwargs={})
thr.start()
sleep(1)
thr=threading.Thread(target=play,args=([sound,0.1]),kwargs={})
thr.start()
sleep(5)
```

but in this example I have a lag on the last played sample.
also I'd like to have 8 channels with 8 samples.

what's wrong with this code?
there are better ways or libraries for this purpose?

**EDIT**
I tried using channels but I still have lags when playing sound2

```
from time import sleep
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
channel1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
channel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)

sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('piano.wav') #duration 4s
sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('kick.wav') #duration <1s

channel1.play(sound1)
channel2.play(sound2)
sleep(0.25)
channel2.stop()
channel2.play(sound2)
sleep(0.25)
channel2.stop()
channel2.play(sound2)
sleep(0.25)
channel2.stop()
channel2.play(sound2)
sleep(5)
```

Comment: The code needs to use multiple channels, as (with a single channel) playing a new sound stops the first sound.  This answer covers it well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38033438/1730895

Comment: @Kingsley it didn't solve, see edit

Comment: Can you please describe what "lags" means.  To me "lag" is something becoming slow, or stuttering.  I'm wondering if there's some extra silence, or some other audio issue in the `kick.wav` file (like a bit of silence before the sound starts).  If you comment out the last 3 plays of sound2 does the first play also have lag?

Comment: There's a delay between the 2nd and the 3rd play of sound2, the first always plays right. If I add at the end other 2 plays of sound2 I also have a delay between the 5th and the 6th.