# Is there a way to play multiple mp3 files at once in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to play 2 mp3 files, but every time the other one plays, the first one stops. Whenever I use channel, the game ends up crashing.

Here is my code:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
#insert generic if statement here
pygame.mixer.music.load("differentmusic.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

is there any way to allow 2 mp3 files to be playing at the same time, or do I have to convert them all to wav?

Comment: Can you please update your question to indicate how converting the `mp3` to `wav` *will* allow simultaneous playback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign sounds to channels in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028970/how-to-assign-sounds-to-channels-in-pygame)

Comment: @Kingsley That requires var????

Comment: also apparently you need wav to use the pygame.mixer.Sound(), which is apparently required to play dual sounds with pygame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so there's a formal answer to this question...

It's not possible to play multiple `MP3` sound files simultaneously using channels with PyGame.  They *can* be played singularly with the `pygame.mixer.music` set of functions.

However, it's absolutely possible to convert your sound-files to [OGG sound format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) - which is compressed much the same as MP3, or the uncompressed WAV format.  Obviously this is not a solution if you want to write an MP3 music player, but for a game it's a minor a requirement.  Free software such as [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) is easily able to convert sound formats.

I have adapted the example from the [comment link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028970/how-to-assign-sounds-to-channels-in-pygame) to not use the `var` module.  Like the linked code it continuously plays a rain-sound , and pressing <kbd>h</kbd> adds a car horn *meep-meep* into the output.

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

DARK_BLUE = (   3,   5,  54)

### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Multi Sound")

### sound
# create separate Channel objects for simultaneous playback
channel1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(0) # argument must be int
channel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)

# Rain sound from: https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/sound-of-rain-falling-mp3/ (CC BY 4.0)
rain_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'rain-falling.ogg' )
channel1.play( rain_sound, -1 )   # loop the rain sound forever

# Car Horn sound from: https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/car-horn-sound-effect/ (CC BY 4.0)
horn_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'car-horn.ogg' )

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYUP ):
            if ( event.key == pygame.K_h ):
                if ( not channel2.get_busy() ):                          # play horn if not already playing
                    channel2.play( horn_sound )
                    print( 'meep-meep' )

    # Window just stays blue
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: When I do this it says that my ogg file can't be opened. I am quite sure this is because it's located in the wrong place, but here is the exact wording for reference:
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'Giorno.ogg'

Comment: Could you explain how I would have to organize my files for this to work?

Comment: For this example, the .ogg files were just in the same directory as the code, and I ran the program *from* this directory.  I downloaded the .mp3 files (from the links commented in the code), used the sound-editing program "Audacity" to save them as .ogg.  Typically you'd get this error if it can't find the file at the given path, or it's somehow not an .ogg file.

Comment: Can't you just change the .mp3 at the end of the file to .ogg?

Comment: @BenDover - No the layout of the internal sound data is completely different.  It needs to be converted.  It's like .DOC and .PDF, they might look the same to the eye, but are completely different inside.